# RStudio and R have different `~` (Home) directories

Tags: r, rstudio, renviron

I have just updated my R version from 4.1.1 to 4.2.2.  My problem is that RStudio (2022.07.2) is not appearing to process the .Renviron file correctly.

In other words, I get the following in the console:

```
> path.expand("~")
[1] "C:/Users/username/Documents"
> Sys.getenv("home")
[1] "C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc/Documents"
```

I suspect that a part of the problem was that version 4.1.1 was moved to a OneDrive folder by my company's IT department whereas 4.2.2 is not on a OneDrive folder.

The problem with RStudio not recognising `~` is that I refer to `~` numerous times in my existing code to point to the OneDrive directory and its numerous subfolders.

One thing that is odd is that I get the following when I run R directly.

```
> path.expand("~")
[1] "C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc/Documents"
```

I have searched my c: drive for .Renviron files and can only find 2:

1. Located in `C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc`, which I presume was created for 4.1.1.
2. Located in `C:/Users/username`, which I presume was created for 4.2.2.
   Both of these version include the following lines:

```
RUSER=C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc/Documents
HOME=C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc/Documents
```

I've also checked both versions' copy of the .Rprofile files.  Both include these lines:

```
Sys.setenv(HOME="C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc/Documents")
Sys.setenv(R_USER="C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc/Documents")
```

A workaround is to start every R script with the `Sys.setenv(HOME="C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc/Documents")`, though that would seem like it defeats the purpose of .Renviron.

I've spent literally hours googling to find a solution, which I suspect is related to migrating from a version inside OneDrive to one outside of OneDrive.
Pages that I've studied include (but not limited to):

- https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf
- [Cannot locate .Rprofile file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459353/cannot-locate-rprofile-file)
- [Tilde expansion in RStudio on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918639/tilde-expansion-in-rstudio-on-windows)
- [RStudio home directory doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834268/rstudio-home-directory-doesnt-exist)
- [Difference between tilde expansion in RStudio and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312923/difference-between-tilde-expansion-in-rstudio-and-r)
- [Tilde "~" expression not functioning in "R"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400903/tilde-expression-not-functioning-in-r)

Comment: I'm wondering if the Rstudio sessions are still using R 4.1.1?

Comment: What does `Sys.getenv("R_USER")` show you in RStudio?  That's what the help page says `path.expand("~")` should be giving you.  And does the source for `path.expand` look different in the two cases?

Comment: BTW, some of the links you posted are to really old articles.  I wouldn't expect R and RStudio to be the same today as they were 6 or 7 years ago.

Comment: @user2554330, R returns `C:/Users/username/OneDrive - Co Inc/Documents` with 'Sys.getenv("R_USER")`.
I'm not sure what you mean by the second question; how do I check the source for `path.expand`.

Comment: @IRTFM, I'm alternating the R version in RStudio (using Global Options). It's still working fine with 4.1.1; the issues are when I attempt to run RStudio with 4.2.2.

Comment: @user2554330, yes, they are old articles, which reflects that there aren't many. I found, for instance, that I overlooked the references to using `setwd()` as I work entirely in projects.  I'm very grateful for your help with this.

Comment: @JamesN. I don't think you are addressing my question. What happens when you start up a session. What is the version of R that "appears" on startup? Or, if you are deep in a session and the stupid, brain-dead Rstudio limitation on how much history and output is retained is in effect, what is the output of `R.version`?

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM.  I was going off the RStudio startup console message.
Here's the output of 'R.version' (thanks - I didn't know that command)
``'platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
crt            ucrt
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          2.2
year           2022
month          10
day            31
svn rev        83211
language       R
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting```
Each time I run the commands in my OP, I'm running them as soon as I open RStudio.

Comment: @JamesN, to see the source for `path.expand` just type that at the console.  The standard R source is very short, just a call to `.Internal(path.expand(path))`.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330.
The only difference between opening RStudio with R version 4.1.1 and 4.2.2 is the bytecode.
Version 4.2.2's response is:
> path.expand
function (path) 
.Internal(path.expand(path))
<bytecode: 0x000001de1a361fb0>
<environment: namespace:base>
whereas version 4.1.1 response is
> path.expand
function (path) 
.Internal(path.expand(path))
<bytecode: 0x000001eaa8942850>
<environment: namespace:base>
I'm unfamiliar with what the bytecode means and whether this difference is significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documents say that on Windows, `path.expand("~")` will give the contents of the `R_USER` environment variable.  The Windows FAQ also mentions that R looks at the `HOME` environment variable if `R_USER` is not set.  If you are getting different results in RStudio vs. R, it must be because of some difference in those environment variables.  The way to see their settings is to start a new session and run

```
Sys.getenv("HOME")
Sys.getenv("R_USER")
```

If you don't see any differences in the results between the two systems, then something very strange is going on, but I think you will.  So the next step is to figure out where the difference came from.

You mention two `.Renviron` files containing settings for `RUSER` and `HOME`. If that's not a typo on the first one, then those files aren't setting `R_USER` (it's not the same as `RUSER`) and `HOME` looks the same,
so you need to look somewhere else for where `R_USER` is coming from.

There are several ways to set environment variables in Windows.  I've never used Windows 11 so it's possible things have changed, but the basic methods in previous versions are these:

- Set system-wide or user-specific environment variables in the "Settings".
- Set session-specific environment variables in a command shell.
- (Maybe, I forget...) Set shortcut-specific environment variables.

In R, there are also several different places to look for `.Renviron` or `.Rprofile` or one of the system versions of those files:  see the `?Startup` help page for the gory details.  Somewhere in there you should find the bad setting that RStudio is using.

Comment: Oh dearie me!  It was the "RUSER" typo in the .Renviron file for version 4.2.2.  I don't know how many times I looked at that line!  Thank you @user2554330.
I'm feeling a bit embarrassed for this mistake.  Thank you, again, for your persistence!